# loop through a list and convert a column to datatime

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

I have a list that contains dataframes. I want to loop though each dataframe in the list and for each dataframe select column 'Time' and convert it to a datetime object. This is the code that I wrote but it gives the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFrame"

```
for i in list_of_dataframes:
  list_of_dataframes[i].to_datetime(list_of_dataframes[i].eventTime)
```

Comment: `i.eventTime`? Although it's also looking strange. Can you provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is immediately at the front:

```
for i in list_of_dataframes:
  list_of_dataframes[i] ...
```

`i` is a data frame, just as you asked.  Why are you trying to use it as an index into the list of data frames?  Try this, instead:

```
for df in list_of_dataframes:
  df.to_datetime(df.eventTime)
```

Since you failed to supply the required full example, I need to ask: does your data frame class even *have* a `to_datetime` method?  If not, you'll need to correct that call to employ the object that *does* have the method you need.

Comment: you are right! I get an error: " 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime' ". My columns are 'id,' 'eventTime,' 'value.'